# how do I handle committing two transactions?

Tags: .net, transactions, npgsql, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I am currently in the situation where I need to commit two transaction,
one going towards the database (postgres, interacted with the npgsql library), and the one going on a kafka message bus (interacted with the confluent.kafka library).

Both support sending/inserting data in transaction, but I am currently having issues with
determining how I should commit both the database transaction and messagebus transaction, since I need to perform a rollback on the other in case it fails.

My initial strategy was to do a

```
try
{
 database.commit()
}
catch
{
 messagebus.abort();
 throw;
}

messagebus.commit()
```

but this then does not cover the case where committing changes to kafka fails, triggers a rollback.

Can I somehow ensure both cases in anyway?

Comment: This is a typical case of a distributed transaction. Take a look at the Outbox Pattern ([here](https://www.kamilgrzybek.com/design/the-outbox-pattern/), [here](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/outbox/)), which was created to prevent needing distributed transactions.

Comment: @Steven what about using savepoints to rollback a committed transaction?

Comment: You can try implementing a two-phase commit model, but I'd stay away from distributed transactions. There's a lot written about the dangers and downsides of distributed transactions.